# Activeadmin form select dropdown update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a Category Model and a SubCategory Model and id like the SubCategory select input to refresh depending on the SubCategories that are associated to the specific Category I have selected.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :title
        f.input :category, as: :select, collection: Category.all, :input_html => { :class => 'chzn-select', :width => 'auto', "data-placeholder" => 'Click' }
        f.input :sub_category, as: :select, collection: SubCategory.all, :input_html => { :class => 'chzn-select', :width => 'auto', "data-placeholder" => 'Click' }
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use dependent select for this purpose.
Example is given [here](http://github.com/abhidsm/dependent-select)

Active Admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register CatalogsProduct do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :product, :as => :select, :collection => Product.all.collect {|product| [product.name, product.id] }
      f.input :catalog, :as => :select, :input_html => {'data-option-dependent' => true, 'data-option-url' => '/products/:catalogs_product_product_id/catalogs', 'data-option-observed' => 'catalogs_product_product_id'}, :collection => (resource.product ? resource.product.category.catalogs.collect {|catalog| [catalog.attr_name, catalog.id]} : []) 
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Catalog controller

```
class CatalogsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    if params[:product_id]
      product = Product.find_by_id(params[:product_id])
      @catalogs = product.category.catalogs
    else
      @catalogs = Catalog.all
    end
    render :json => @catalogs.collect {|catalog| {:id => catalog.id, :name => catalog.attr_name} }
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're lazy and just want make strings try this: `f.input :status, as: :select, collection: (["new", "checked_in", "called","complete"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this, I did it by relating games to categories and subcategories.
Working on Ruby on Rails 6.0.4 and Active Admin 2.9.0.

**Models**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sub_category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :sub_categories
end

class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Active admin form**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Game do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: Category.all
      f.input :sub_category_id, as: :select, collection: ([]) # The input is initialized without values
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

You must do the following:

1. Create a controller, that returns the subcategories.

   ```
   class SubCategoriesController < ApplicationController

     def sub_category_filter
       if params[:category_id]
         category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
         @sub_categories = category.sub_categories
       else
         @sub_categories = []
       end
       render :json => @sub_categories.collect {|sub_category| {:id => sub_category.id, :name => sub_category.name} }
      end

   end
   ```
2. Add the route in the `routes.rb` file.

   ```
   get 'sub_category_filter/' => 'sub_category#sub_category_filter'
   ```
3. Inspect with your web browser console your selects, and use a CSS selector to create a jQuery object for the category select, something like:

   ```
   $('#game_category_id')
   ```
4. Add this block of code in the file  `/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`, which is responsible for making the call to the generated controller, and adding the options that it returns.

   ```
   //= require active_admin/base
   $(function () {
     $('#game_category_id').on('change', function () {
       $('#game_sub_category_id option').remove(); // Remove all <option> child tags.
       $.getJSON(`/sub_category_filter`, {category_id: $(this).val()}, function(result){ // Documentation on getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
         $.each(result, function (i, item) { // Iterates through a collection
           $('#game_sub_category_id').append($('<option>', { // Append an object to the inside of the select box
               value: item.id,
               text : item.name 
           }));
         });
       });
     })
   })
   ```

**References:**

[Can't find the error in my dependent select drop down on Active Admin( Rails 3.2, Active Admin 1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335705/cant-find-the-error-in-my-dependent-select-drop-down-on-active-admin-rails-3-2)

[Populate Select box options on click with Javascript/Jquery with Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233464/populate-select-box-options-on-click-with-javascript-jquery-with-json-data)

Comment: This solution is working for me as well. Rails 7 and activeadmin (2.13.1)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a member action (method: GET, params: the id of the selected Category) in the ActiveAdmin Category model that returns the SubCategories (in json, for example) belongs to the selected Category:

   https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/8-custom-actions.md#member-actions
2. You have to use jQuery (for exmaple) with ajax, that populate the SubCategory select input when the Category select input has been changed:

   [Populate Select box options on click with Javascript/Jquery with Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233464/populate-select-box-options-on-click-with-javascript-jquery-with-json-data)
   https://forum.jquery.com/topic/best-practices-for-populating-selects-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this  to add specific selection

```
form do |f|
            f.inputs do
            f.input :category , :as => :select, collection: (['conversion','double-bar', 'fixed-hybrid','removal-bar-over-denture', 'surgical-guides'])
  
            end
            actions 
          end
```