# One input dependent on other input field in activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

Let's say I have a model:

```
class User
 has_many :books
end

class Book
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Now in active admin, I want when I select any user. The form will only display books created by that user.

```
forms do |f|
 f.inputs do
  f.input :user, as: :select, collection: User.all
  f.input :books, as: :select,  collection: Book.all
 end
 f.actions
end
```

What is the query to replace `Book.all`?

Comment: I think you need javascript to solve this problem. Because it is not decided which user will be selected until the page loads and you select a user from select box.

Comment: [ActiveAdmin Addons](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons) gem provides option to integrate [nested select](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#nested-select-input) in ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 2):

This work for me on dependend "select" on Rails 6.0.4

**Models**

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord 
 belongs_to :sector
 belongs_to :sub_sectors
end

class Sector < ApplicationRecord 
 has_many :sub_sectors
end

class SubSector < ApplicationRecord 
 belongs_to :sector
end
```

**Active admin form**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Organization do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :sector, as: :select, collection: Sector.all
        f.input :sub_sector_id, as: :select, collection: ([]) # The input is initialized without values
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

You must do the following:

1. Create a controller, that returns the subsectors.

   ```
   class SubSectorsController < ApplicationController

     def sub_sectors_filter
       if params[:sector_id]
         sector = Sector.find(params[:sector_id])
         @sub_sectors = sector.sub_sectors
       else
         @sub_sectors = []
       end
       render :json => @sub_sectors.collect {|sub_sector| {:id => sub_sector.id, :name => sub_sector.name} }
      end

   end
   ```
2. Add the route in the `routes.rb` file.

   ```
   get 'sub_sectors_filter/' => 'sub_sectors#sub_sectors_filter'
   ```
3. Inspect with your web browser console your selects, and use a CSS selector to create a jQuery object for the sector select, something like:

   ```
   $('#organization_sector_id')
   ```
4. Add this block of code in the file  `/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`, which is responsible for making the call to the generated controller, and adding the options that it returns.

   ```
   //= require active_admin/base
   $(function () {
     $('#organization_sector_id').on('change', function () {
       $('#organization_sub_sector_id option').remove(); // Remove all <option> child tags.
       $.getJSON(`/sub_sectors_filter`, {sector_id: $(this).val()}, function(result){ // Documentation on getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
         $.each(result, function (i, item) { // Iterates through a collection
           $('#organization_sub_sector_id').append($('<option>', { // Append an object to the inside of the select box
               value: item.id,
               text : item.name 
           }));
         });
       });
     })
   })
   ```

**References:**

[Can't find the error in my dependent select drop down on Active Admin( Rails 3.2, Active Admin 1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335705/cant-find-the-error-in-my-dependent-select-drop-down-on-active-admin-rails-3-2)

[Populate Select box options on click with Javascript/Jquery with Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233464/populate-select-box-options-on-click-with-javascript-jquery-with-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

As [Sampat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788206/sampat-badhe) mentioned in the comment you can use ActiveAdmin [nested select addon](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_nested_select.md).

After installing `activeadmin_addons` gem, you can use:

```
  forms do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :user_id, as: :nested_select,
                        level_1: { attribute: :user_id, collection: User.all },
                        level_2: { attribute: :book_id, collection: Book.all }
    end
    f.actions
  end
```